# Method of characteristic for PDE $xu_x + yu_y = u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm studying method of characteristic. This is a homework. I'm very new to this topic so hope anyone can give a direction.

> Given a PDE : $xu_x + yu_y = u$.
>
> a) Solve it, where the initial curve is $u=1$ along $y=x^2, x>0$.
>
> b) Find classes of function $f(t)$ that satisfy the initial curve satisfying $u=-f(t)$ along the arc parameterized by $x=t, y=t, t>0$ such that the problem has infinitely many solutions.

For a), I write $dx/dt=x$, and so on for the characteristic equation, obtaining $x=Ae^t, y=Be^t, u=Ce^t$. I also write $x(0,s)=s, y(0,s)=s^2, u(0,s)=1$ for the initial curve. I can see that the Jacobian is nonzero. Thus, unique solution is expected. Solving the given data, I have $u=x^2/y$.
Is this a right solution?

For b), I use the same method. Writing exactly the same as a) for the characteristic equation, obtaining the same functions in $t$. The initial curve is $x(0,s)=s, y(0,s)=s, u(0,s)=-f(s)$ (where I just switched the variable to $s$ instead of $t$ from the problem. And indeed, the Jacobian is zero, so it'll have infinitely many solutions or no solution. Now, I don't know where to go. I somehow realize I don't understand problem b). Should I just choose one $f(t)$ and add constant in it..or..how?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For a) it's OK. For b) Don't use the condition $y=x^2$ from a) which is non longer valid. The new condition is $y=x$. You should find  infinity many solutions if $f(t)= c\,t$ or  no solution if $f(t)\neq c\,t$

Comment: Ah sorry I mistyped it. It should've been $y(0,s)=s$. Thanks. I don't get it btw. I have $x=Ae^t, y=Be^t, u=Ce^t$, where $A, B, C$ are functions of s. From there I get $u=e^t$ and $x=y$. I would like to reach the same conclusion as yours, but can't find how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was mainly given in comments. This is another approach which is too long to be posted in comments.

The characteristics equation is $\quad \frac{dx}{x}= \frac{dy}{y}= \frac{du}{u}\quad$ from which we obtain : 
$\begin{cases}
\frac{y}{x}=c_1 \\
\frac{u}{x}=c_2 \\
\end{cases}$

The general solution expressed on implicit form is : $\quad \Phi \left( \frac{y}{x} \:,\: \frac{u}{x} \right) = 0\quad$ where $\Phi$ is any derivable function of two variables.

It can be solved for $u$ leading to the equivalent explicit form :
$$u(x,y)=x\:F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
where $F$ is any derivable function.

a) Condition $u=1$ along $y=x^2$

$u=1=x\:F\left(\frac{x^2}{x}\right)=x\:F(x)\quad \implies \quad F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\quad$ on the curve characteristic.

Elsewhere  $\quad u=x\:\left(\frac{1}{\frac{y}{x}}\right)$
$$u(x,y)= \frac{x^2}{y} $$

b) Condition  $u=-f(t)$ along $y=x=t$

$u=-f(t)=t\:F\left(\frac{t}{t}\right)=t\:F(1)= c\:t\quad$ where $c=F(1)=$constant.

If $f(t)=-c\:t\quad \implies u(x,y)=x\:F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\quad$ An infinity of functions $F$ such $F(1)=c$ are convenient, so an infinity of solutions.

If $f(t)\neq -c\:t\quad $ the non-linear function $f(t)$ cannot be equal to a linear function $t\:F(1)\quad$ : no solution.

Comment: How do you find the general solution? Your solution looks good but I can't understand your argument before the line "a) Condition ... " It's OK if I don't know how to conclude f(t) = ct from my statement in the comment, but instead using your argument. But I hope i can understand how the general solution is obtained. Thx

Comment: For example, you can find several applications of this method in the paper : https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/436.A1.12f/PDE_Meth_Characteristics.pdf .

Comment: Thanks.. But I wonder why I can't use parameterization to obtain the same result. I have $x(t,s)=Ae^t, y(t,x)=Be^t, u(t,s)=Ce^t$ where A, B, C are functions of s. I also have $x(0,s) = r, y(0,s) = r, u(0,s) = -f(r)$ where I have used the variable r instead of t from the problem. Hence, $u=-f(r)x/r$. It looks like every function $f(r)$ is just fine. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I almost understand what you mean. I accepted it as the answer, but could you please elaborate more on how to solve for general solution $u$ explicitly from the implicit form?

Comment: Issue 1 : From the characteristics equation  we draw two ODEs to be solved solved. The goal is to express the two relationsships on the form of equations equal to constants.  First : $\frac{dx}{x}-\frac{dy}{y}=0$ with its solution $\ln(x)-\ln(y)=$constant, or on another form $\frac{y}{x}=c_1$. Second  : $\frac{du}{u}-\frac{dx}{x}=0$ with its solution $\ln(u)-\ln(x)=$constant, or on another form $\frac{u}{x}=c_2$ . Alternatively one could use $\frac{du}{u}-\frac{dy}{y}=0$ which would lead to a different typography of the further founctions, but finally to equivalent result.

Comment: Issue 2 : In any equation $\Phi(c_1\:,\:c_2)=0$  remplacing $c_1$ and $c_2$ by the respective functions $\frac{y}{x}$ and $\frac{u}{x}$ gives an implicit solution. An equivalent form of relationship is for example $c_2=F(c_1)$ leading to $\frac{u}{x}=F(\frac{y}{x})$ . This is useful if $u$ appears only in one of the two functions, because the equation becomes explicite in some cases. The present case gives  $u=xF(\frac{y}{x})$. Of course all this comes from the general theory of the characteristics method, but on a simplified form which is usefull in some relatively simple cases of PDEs.

Comment: See the theorem 2.5 , page 4, in the paper cited (above link). Nevertheless I advise to  continue tu study the parametrization in theory and practice of the method of characteristics.